# Why the model "FourierAnalysis" does not run on OpenModelica? error: lvalue required as unary '&' operand

Tags: fft, modelica, openmodelica

The test model "TestSine" from the package "Sensors.Tests.FourierAnalysis" from the Xogeny library: https://github.com/xogeny/Sensors does not run on OpenModelica.

The error message is: "error: lvalue required as unary '&' operand". In the C-file generated by OpenModelica, the message error is about this lines:

*infoStreamPrint(LOG_EVENTS, 0, "reinit $Panalysis$Pai$lB1$rB  = %f", 0.0);
    copy_real_array_data_mem(&0.0, &$Panalysis$Pai$lB1$rB);*

I don't understand this message and I want to use the block "FourierAnalysis" with OpenModelica.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was an implementation bug in OpenModelica; it has been fixed in [r22261](https://trac.openmodelica.org/OpenModelica/changeset/22261).

Note: Bug reports should ideally be reported to https://trac.openmodelica.org/OpenModelica/newticket